# Do "in future" and "in the future" imply different meanings?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, determiners

Do *in future* and *in the future* imply different meanings? If so, using which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: Can you give some examples for context?

Comment: Maybe Hamid is asking about the difference between "in future" and "in the future"?

Comment: @Shinto Yes, exactly, that. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Can you give sentences?  If the sentence is "Be careful in future", then I would tell you that the sentence was just a note (or written by a non-native speaker) and should normally have "the" in front of it.  If the sentence is "I hope to see you again in future meetings", then I would tell you that "future" is being used as an adjective.  Or, maybe there is some context where "in future" would be used that I am not thinking of.

Comment: In future just sounds like bad grammar.

Comment: I agree with user680. I clicked on Shinto's google search and most of the results seem to be found on web forums where people are too lazy to add "the" between "in" and "future". Also, I would not expect a native English speaker to actually say "...in future" as opposed to "...in the future".

Comment: Well, I’ll be damned. “In future” seems plainly ungrammatical to my native speaker intuition, but I went and looked in COCA and there are tons of examples.

Comment: @nohat, @user680: I always assumed the "in future" was simple laziness that assumed a place in the language over time.

Comment: We don't even know what we are answering without examples.

Comment: Where Americans would use the phrase "In the future", Britons would almost always use "In future". In future, I would hope to hear fewer questions of this sort.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> He would be more careful in future.
>   They plan on getting married in the near future.

In the first sentence, "in future" means "from now on"; the NOAD says its use is chiefly British.
In the second sentence, "in the future" means "the time or a period of time following the moment of speaking or writing."

Comment: I'd say "exclusively British." I don't believe I've ever heard it from Americans.

Comment: What is the origin of the expression "in future"? It does sound odd. Could it be an ellipsis of some specified or implied noun, as in "in future events" or "in future times"?

Comment: @Pifagor: it is an adverbially phrase. I doubt it is short for anything. It is clearly Latinate: Latin has no articles (the, a, an) so a preposition followed by a noun is common (http://www.yuni.com/library/latin_3.html): e.g. "in loco parentis" (in place of the parent), an adverbially phrase (used in English/legal jargon). In fact, "in futuro" is the Latin equivalent to "in future", so American English added an unnecessary word. By the way, adjectives can be used as nouns (substantives): the young, the restless, the good, the bad, the ugly, without needing a noun to modify.

Comment: This earned a down-vote on two counts. I don't see any difference between the two definitions. "The time or a period of time following the moment of speaking or writing," is just a longer way of saying "from now on". Also a poor example has been chosen, with 'near' qualifying the second case.

Answer (score 14):

*In future* is commonly used in British English and is perfectly correct but has a different meaning than *in the future*.

*In the future* refers to an unspecified point in time, while *in future* means from now on.

> It'a shame I missed you when I popped round to see you yesterday. I'll ring up beforehand **in future**.
>
> **In the future** people will look back at the mobile phones we use today and laugh at their simplicity.

Answer (score 12):

*In future* is how they say it in the UK and India. It is common and considered normal.

> In future, we will avoid water beds.

In American English, *In future* sounds strange; *in the future* is preferred or at least will get you fewer strange looks.

Comment: "Less strange looks" or "fewer strange looks"? Or both? :-)

Comment: also in Hong Kong; I imagine in other chiefly-UK-influenced Englishes as well

Answer (score 9):

You may see "in future" when "future" is modifying a noun for which "in" is an appropriate preposition.

Fore example:

in future `______`

- shows
- plays
- events

and etc.

Answer (score 7):

*In future* is much more common in the UK and Ireland, as in *In future, be more careful.* In the US, we would tend to say *In the future, be more careful.* They mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: +1.When Indian customer service representatives are taught American English, this is something that is part of the curriculum.

Comment: I learned about this difference from an Indian co-worker.

Answer (score 3):

Both forms are possible. "In future" is often used in reprimands:

> In future please sign and date your letters

It is very general, talking about all times from now onwards. You can [find many examples on Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22in+future+please+take+care%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) (search for "in future please take care").

"In the future" is more neutral and more specific:

> In the future I would like to go to Australia, but now I don't have enough money.

Comment: I have never, ever, seen "In future" use as a reprimanding replacement for "in the future."  If you can show a documented use, i will remove my down-vote, and delete my own answer.

Comment: @Shinto: Clearly, I meant something that you did not invent.

Comment: @John: Google for, e.g. "in future please take care" to find several examples.

Comment: Alright, +1.  Tho, I only think that this is 1/2 of the answer.  I'm modifying mine rather than removing.

Comment: I think it's important to note that "in future please take care" is mostly a feature of *written* English. Sort of a telegraph ellipsis. No one would speak that sentence.

Comment: Interestingly, "in future please take care" returns over 295,000 hits, whereas "in the future please take care" only returns about 37000. Yet, in my experience, (US New England and Midwest regions), I have never heard "in future" used this way, either colloquially or in formal speech. Is there a regional variance of which I am unaware?

Comment: @Shinto, I'm going to need some convincing that Google isn't giving  you results from non-native speakers.

Comment: *in future* would never be used in my area of America, the southwest. I've never heard or seen that. The only place I can imagine it is in text when letters are precious and limited.

Comment: @JSBangs: You can just examine the Google results yourself, and see who wrote them!

Answer (score 2):

The difference is only in whether *future* is a noun or an adjective.

*In the future, please be more careful* and *Please be more careful in the future* both use *future* as a noun.

*In future activities, please be more careful* uses *future* to modify the noun *activities.*

To my knowledge is it not correct to say *in future* in the place of *in the future.*

Answer (score 1):

As far as grammar goes the difference between *in future* and *in the future* is contextual.
One usually comes across phrases like *in future endeavours* or *in future meets* where future serves as an adjective.
But if the reference is only to the times ahead,*in the future* would be correct and not *in future*.
Thus,it would be correct to say:
Be more careful *in the future*.
or 
There will come a time *in the future* when there will be no petroleum left on the planet.
and incorrect to go with the other.
However,the spoken word in Britain and many former colonies where the influence of British English is enduring,it's not uncommon to come across simple notes that use *in future*. 
Perhaps they find it more easy on their ears.Nonetheless,grammatically wanting.

Comment: Grammatically wanting? This isn't Latin we are discussing. English is a language of idiom. And idiomatically *in future* has a quite different meaning to *in the future*. Merging the two curtails articulation and dumbs down the language.